# JetBrains MPS-Building from source code

Tags: intellij-idea, mps

Has Anyone tried building MPS source code from build scripts instead running from IntelliJ IDE. I tried but I am getting a build failure with below error message "class jetbrains.sign.JetSignTask not found".Any Idea?

Thanks in Advance

Kunal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the error. Only a dedicated JetBrains machine can sign the generated jar files.